# How to group and count items in groups and get the full row?

Tags: sql, t-sql

This query gets the desired rows -grouped by subject- and I also want to know the items count in each group.

```
SELECT log.* FROM [hm_deliverylog] AS log
WHERE log.deliveryid IN
    (
        SELECT MAX([deliveryid])  FROM [hm_deliverylog]
        WHERE [deliverytime] > DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY deliverysubject
    )

ORDER BY deliveryid DESC
```

How can I count the groups? Like below?

```
SELECT joined.groupcount, log.* FROM [hm_deliverylog] AS log
```

P.S: Imagine the Gmail inbox; it displays the newest message and shows the message count. I want to group the messages with same subject and count them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put the `COUNT()` calculation in the subquery and instead of using `IN`, make that a derived table to be joined:

```
SELECT log.* 
     , grp.cnt AS groupcount
FROM 
    [hm_deliverylog] AS log
  JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX([deliveryid]) AS deliveryid
             , COUNT(*) AS cnt  
        FROM [hm_deliverylog]
        WHERE [deliverytime] > DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY deliverysubject
    ) AS grp
    ON grp.deliveryid = log.deliveryid
ORDER BY 
    log.deliveryid DESC ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`OVER` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
SELECT COUNT(deliveryid) OVER (PARTITION BY deliverysubject) As GroupCount
```

> Determines the partitioning and ordering of a rowset before the
>   associated window function is applied. That is, the OVER clause
>   defines a window or user-specified set of rows within a query result
>   set. A window function then computes a value for each row in the
>   window. You can use the OVER clause with functions to compute
>   aggregated values such as moving averages, cumulative aggregates,
>   running totals, or a top N per group results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT log.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY deliverysubject) AS groupcount 
FROM [hm_deliverylog] AS log
GROUP BY deliverysubject
```